# Painting over lead based varnish

Tags: varnishing, lead

Can I paint over lead based varnish with a primer and paint without stripping the varnish?

Comment: Is the varnish peeling?

Comment: Is the varnish indeed lead based?  Or "I was told" / "must be, it's old" etc.?  Lead being desired for its potency and durability as a colorant, would be of limited value in varnish.  All the sites I see that extol lead in varnish seem to be of the Chicken Little / handwringing / scare you into hiring them style.

Answer (score 1):

"Encapsulating" a lead finish (burying it under another finish) is in fact one standard way of mitigating lead risk. Not knowing the varnish in question, I would recommend looking for a primer specifically made to stick to both water-based and oil-based finishes; after that it's just normal painting.

But unless you want to paint for the sake of painting, I would strongly recommend testing the existing finish to determine whether it really contains/releases lead or not. Most US hardware stores, and some paint stores, carry tests for lead paint; they're inexpensive, they're reasonably safe if handled correctly, and they work.